# When I ping the RDS endpoint from my computer it shows the Private IP of the RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, rds, vpc

We are trying to configure a VPC, which has a private subnet and a public subnet. In the private subnet there is an RDS which is not publicly accessible. We have test it and seems that works fine! The issue though its that when I ping the RDS endpoint from my computer it returns the Private IP of the RDS (its not returns any packets though).

We do not want to shows the Private IP.

Any help would be appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Have you enabled ping in the security group of the RDS instance?

Comment: Thats a good idea, but I would like to understand why private network reveals the internal IP?

Comment: Can you clarify: why private network reveals internal IP? What is the private network and internal IP that you are referring to?

Comment: A private subnet contains an RDS instance with Private IP (of the instance) xx.xx.xx.xx. I do not want this RDS instance to be accessible through internet, but when I ping it through my home computer it returns the RDS private IP xx.xx.xx.xx. Why is that happening ?

Comment: Just to be clear, when you ping it from home, you're not connected to any sort of VPN?

Comment: @MrDuk No I am not.

Comment: Are you sure the subnet you've setup isn't publicly accessible? Do your route tables allow anything outside of your local network?

Comment: @MrDuk yes the subnet is not publicly accessible for sure. However I need to check the Route Tables I will let you know, good point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went ahead and popped open a chat with our AWS support team to pick their brain. Basically, this boils down to how they host their DNS mappings for RDS endpoints; they're created in a public hosted zone by default (not modifiable). Hence, you can resolve your RDS endpoint over the internet (because *the mapping* is hosted publicly), but can't actually route any data to it.

If this is an issue, to get around it you can ... jump through some hoops:

> *An alternative will be to create a private hosted zone with a record
>   that points to the rds endpoint. (for example a private hosted zone
>   "xxxx.com" that has an alias record pointing to rds endpoint), in which case you will reach out to your rds instance
>   using xxxxx.com*

However, this doesn't actually disable the original AWS created endpoint from returning the private IP, it just allows you to configure an endpoint that doesn't.

For what it's worth, revealing your private IP is pretty harmless; several thousand devices likely share your exact private IP. The only way this information would be concerning for you is if an attacker was actually in your network - and at that point... they could just do a lookup on the DNS from there to get the IP.

Answer (score 1):

First question: why do you want to do this? Your 10.1.2.3 or 172.31.2.3 or whatever is a non-routable address. It really doesn't matter whether people know it if they can't get into your VPC.

As for actually preventing it, you can't: Amazon makes the endpoint available via DNS (you can use `nslookup` to find it). You could always try filing a support ticket, but I wouldn't expect any results.

Also, FYI the second component of the endpoint is related to your account. So in your image you redacted non-important information but left the (potentially) important information present.

---

In case it's not clear, the problem is in how Amazon resolves DNS requests, *not* in how the networks are connected. Here's an example of an `nslookup` call for one of our database instances that's running on a private subnet. This is from my PC, *not* connected to the VPC via VPN or any other means:

```
> nslookup REDACTED.REDACTED.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
Server:     127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   REDACTED.REDACTED.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
Address: 10.1.56.119
```

Comment: Thats reasonable to ask, but if I ping any other public address it does not reveal its private IP.

Comment: @GeorgeVardikos - that's because those hosts have a public address. Amazon is perhaps being sloppy in returning the private IP for a public DNS lookup, but that's what they do. I recommend spending some time learning about [private IPs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) and [DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System).